# Rounding off to decimals

Tags: r, decimal, probability

I have worked out a probability in r (equal to 1.7715e-06) and I would like to be able to view it to 10 decimal points. Does anybody know how to convert this to 10 decimal points? I've tried using the round() and signific() functions but they aren't useful.

I got this answer (1.7715e-06) using:

```
dbinom(11, 11, 0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
format(round(dbinom(11, 11, 0.3), 10), scientific = F)

#> [1] "0.0000017715"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
options("scipen"=999)
```

Then:

```
.3^11
[1] 0.00000177147
```

or

```
round(.3^11,10)
[1] 0.0000017715
```

or

```
dbinom(11,11,.3)
[1] 0.00000177147
```

or

```
round(dbinom(11,11,.3),10)
[1] 0.0000017715
```